# Invoke wcf data service operation with intellisense

Tags: c#, metadata, wcf-data-services

I have the following WCF Data Service

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyWcfDataService: DataService<MyEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetActiveCustomers()
    {
        return this.CurrentDataSource.Customers.Where(x=> ! x.IsDeleted); 
    }

}
```

On my client side I add a service reference to that service and I am able to query the database as:

```
var context = new ServiceReference.MyWcfDataService(new Uri("http://localhost:10144/Services/MyWcfDataService.svc"));

// I am able to get reports as
var reports = context.Reports.ToList(); 

// now how do I invoke the operation 'GetActiveCustomers'?
// I am looking for something like:
var actCusts = context.Operations.GetActiveCustomers();
```

I know I can invoke the operation by making a request to `http://localhost:10144/Services/MyWcfDataService.svc/GetActiveCustomers` . But then what is the point of visual studio downloading the metadata. Since I am consuming that service also from a .net application it will be nice if I can access that method with intellicense.

**In other words** on my client when I added a reference to that service I could see:

```
<Schema Namespace="WebService.Data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="MyEntities" >
        <EntitySet Name="Customers" ..... etc />
        ... etc
        <FunctionImport Name="GetActiveCustomers" ReturnType="Collection(Customer)"  ... etc />
```

on `service.edmx`. That should be used by Visual Studio to invoke the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the Add Service Reference working on OData V3 (WCF data service) doesn't support automatically generating service operations in .NET client. However, you can write your own methods in *generated service context class* to invoke the operations. Like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> GetActiveCustomers()
{
    Uri requestUri = new Uri(this.BaseUri.OriginalString.Trim('/') + "/GetActiveCustomers");
    return this.Execute<Customer>(requestUri);
}
```

With this you can write `var actCusts = context.GetActiveCustomers();` and get the results back in your .NET application.